# I don't think I'm going to end up at my company's internship - should I tell my manager now?

Tags: resignation, internship

I am currently working a part-time remote gig during my sophomore year; my small company brought me on after my first internship over the summer - it included a (relatively) nice raise with it.

The company I am at now is not my final destination in life and I would like to take internships at larger companies - ones that have the ability to pay up to twice my first internship's.

However, the part-time remote job I have now is very lucrative (few companies keep interns on past the internship) and if I do not secure anything better, I would like to return to it after my summer internship completes.

How can I navigate this that I can get the best of both worlds (better internship and ability to return to job)?

Comment: Why do you have to tell them?

Comment: I feel that if I drop the bomb right before the summer that I don't plan to stay, they may not be gracious in letting me back on 3 months later. They'll probably ask on their own at some point, regardless.

Answer (score 7):

> I don't think I'm going to end up at my companies internship - should I tell my manager now?

No. You don't need to tell your current manager anything.

You should continue doing the best possible job at your currently company.

Then, next year, you can search and apply for internship at bigger companies if you want to.

In the future, after you graduate, you can apply for full time positions at all companies that you have done internships at.

Answer (score 6):

One of the Golden Rules of Corporate work - never announce anything that you haven't confirmed.

The only time a Manager needs to know that you are applying for other opportunities is when you hand them your Resignation Letter.